# Can I drag the content inside of the cell in ag-grid so that I copy it?

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid seems to block the mouse drag event for the content inside of the cell by default and I’m looking to find any option or something to unblock it if it’s possible. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's a css class `ag-unselectable` added by ag-grid over the grid that prevents the content inside the cells from being selected by dragging the mouse. You can override this behavior by adding the following css class in your styles.

```
  .ag-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    -moz-user-select: auto !important;
    -ms-user-select: auto !important;
    user-select: auto !important;
  }
```

Comment: Turns out there’s `enableCellTextSelection` option to achieve what I want which has been introduced from the recent ag-grid-community library